# Styling a specific set of input types in a reusable way with Sass

Tags: sass

I'd like to have a mixin function that returns a list of the HTML5 input types. I'd like to manage this in one place, and as new types come up, change the function, not all the places elsewhere in the code.

The problem seems to be that mixins were not designed to return strings that can be used outside of the curly braces in CSS. Here is an example of my mixin (currently returning errors) and how I'd use it:

```
/* 
 * Set all the up-and-coming input text types here for easier reference 
 * Does not include types that are not meant to be displayed full width, such as: 
        type=number, type=range, type=date, type=color
 */
@mixin input_text_types( $focus:false ) {
    @if $focus {
        @return #{input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus, input[type=search]:focus, input[type=email]:focus, input[type=url]:focus, input[type=tel]:focus};
    } @else {
        @return #{input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=search], input[type=email], input[type=url], input[type=tel]};
    }
}
```

In use:

```
@include input_text_types() {
    width: 80%; 
}
```

The errors I get are like `error sass/style.scss (Line 134 of sass/_functions.scss: Invalid CSS after "...@return #{input": expected "}", was "[type=text]:foc...")`

I've tried to format the output with and without the `@return` directive, and with different ways I have seen to enclose string values (in quotes, in single quote, in the curly braces with the hash). Anyone ever try to do something like this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem might better be solved by using variables to contain your selectors.  By using a mixin, you're losing the ability to chain it with similar elements.

```
$form-input-text: 'input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], input[type="url"]';
$form-input-buttons: 'input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="button"], button';
$form-input-dates: 'input[type^="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="week"], input[type="time"]';
$form-input-not-radio: 'input:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"])';

#{$form-input-text}, textarea {
    @include border-radius(.25em);
    border: $form-input-border;
}

#{$form-input-text}, textarea, input[type="file"] {
    width: $form-input-width;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield
}

#{$form-input-buttons} {
    padding: .25em .5em;
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course... this makes more sense. I was getting errors when trying to call the mixing in addition to another element, like textarea, so this makes a bunch more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Chris Eppstein on GitHub and [@compass](http://twitter.com/compass) on Twitter, he cleared up [with a gist](https://gist.github.com/chriseppstein/184b2676a8ff0879302a) that I am confusing the way a function works vs. a mixin. With the `@content` directive, I can achieve what I want thusly:

```
@mixin input_text_types( $focus:false ) {
    @if $focus {
      input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus, input[type=search]:focus, input[type=email]:focus, input[type=url]:focus, input[type=tel]:focus {
        @content;
      }
    } @else {
        input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=search], input[type=email], input[type=url], input[type=tel] {
          @content;
        }
    }
}
```

It would still be used in the same way, with the `@include` directive.

For more about the slight differences between `@mixin` and `@function`, read [Pure SASS Functions](http://thesassway.com/advanced/pure-sass-functions).