# Group css selectors in LESS for pseudo class use

Tags: css, less

Say I have a group of elements that I want to apply pseudo classes to, is there a way to define muliple elements in a variable and then apply a pseudo class to all of them at once? Like so:

```
@inputs: input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=password], textarea;

@inputs {
    //some styles;
}

@inputs:focus{
    //some focus-specific styles;
}
```

Apologies if this is too obvious, I am reletively new to LESS

Comment: Sass can do this via *string interpoloation* (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17370693/1652962).  Not sure if this can be applied to LESS.

Comment: @cimmanon: at this particular time (LESS 1.4.1) there appears to be a bug (or lack of a feature) with using a comma separated string in a variable for LESS as a group of selectors, so [I submitted an issue on it](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1421).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do that but this works too. I am assuming you just want to write the long pseudo class once.

```
input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=password], textarea {
   // styles for normal

   &:focus {
      // styles for focus
   }

   &:hover {

   }
}
```