# Add another element type to definition using Sass§

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

Is it possible to add another element to a definition something like

```
input {
    &:not[type="submit"], &,textarea {
        // styles that apply to inputs that are not submit buttons, and text areas
    }
    // other styles here that I don't want to apply to textareas
    // do want to apply to inputs
}
```

I've had a look through the sass documentation but can't see anything, if anyone can suggest a way to do this that would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: The correct not syntax is `&:not([type="submit"])` by the way.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It was actually just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  Keep in mind that nesting is a feature, not a requirement.  Nest when it makes sense, don't nest when it doesn't.

Your problem might be better solved with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17370693/1652962), since there are more than 2 subsets of input elements (text, date, button, checkbox/radio, slider, color picker, etc.) and styles that should be applied to text style inputs generally don't work well on any other type.

Comment: Yes I understand that nesting is a feature not a requirement. Also there are other types of inputs that won't react well to default styling but I don't use them so that's fine, I just wanted an easy way to be able to define the border and font etc for both text inputs and textareas, thank you for the link anyway.

I ended up just defining it like this
`input, textarea { // default styles here } input { // text input styles here } textarea { // textarea styles here }`