# List of items in Sass

Tags: list, sass

I want to define a list of text input selectors in Sass such as:

```
  [type="text"],
  [type="color"],
  [type="date"],
  [type="datetime"],
  [type="datetime-local"],
  [type="email"],
  [type="month"],
  [type="number"],
  [type="range"],
  [type="search"],
  [type="tel"],
  [type="time"],
  [type="url"],
  [type="week"],
```

and then to use that list around my sass code. How can I set those as a variable and then to use them as above elsewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling a specific set of input types in a reusable way with Sass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369600/styling-a-specific-set-of-input-types-in-a-reusable-way-with-sass)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [@each directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive):

```
$types: text, color, date, datetime, datetime-local, email, month, number, range, search, tel, time, url, week;

@each $prop in $types {
  input[type="#{$prop}"] {
    padding: 0;
    // other meaningful properties
  }
}
```

### [SassMeister demo](http://sassmeister.com/gist/eca50a7743d7fb87fb69)

---

As mentioned by @cimmanon, it is true that there will be a lot of selectors which will make the css less readable. It is possible to use the trick from @artlung and combine all selectors into one:

```
$joined-selector: null;

@each $prop in $types {
  $elem: "input[type='#{$prop}']";
  $joined-selector: $joined-selector, $elem;
}

#{$joined-selector} {
  padding: 0;
}
```

### [Updated SassMeister demo](http://sassmeister.com/gist/029671e5d8cd887ef5f0)

That sass code looks rather complex to me. I prefer keeping sass simple and readable and sacrificing readability of the generated css file. As I developer I only maintain sass code, not the css.

Comment: No one would want to do this.  This generates bloated CSS.

Comment: @cimmanon finding solution is an iterative process. My initial answer addressed the problem mentioned by the OP. It is true that the generated css looks unreadable but it keeps the sass file simple.

Answer (score 0):

[**Lists**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists) are worth learning about in SASS.

Addressing your need, let's define your list:

```
$text-input-selectors: "[type='text']" "[type='color']" "[type='date']"
            "[type='datetime']" "[type='datetime-local']"
            "[type='email']" "[type='month']" "[type='number']"
            "[type='range']" "[type='search']" "[type='tel']"
            "[type='time']" "[type='url']" "[type='week']";
```

We can run [**@each**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive) over it and get individual selectors:

```
@each $selector in $text-input-selectors {
   #{$selector} {
      font-weight: normal;
   }
}
```

Result:

```
[type='text'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='color'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='date'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='datetime'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='datetime-local'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='email'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='month'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='number'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='range'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='search'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='tel'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='time'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='url'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[type='week'] {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Or we can run code that concatenates it to a comma separated string:

```
$all-selectors: null;
@each $item in $text-input-selectors {
  $all-selectors: $all-selectors, unquote(#{$item});
}

#{$all-selectors} {
   color: red;  
}
```

Result:

```
[type='text'], [type='color'], [type='date'], [type='datetime'], [type='datetime-local'], [type='email'], [type='month'], [type='number'], [type='range'], [type='search'], [type='tel'], [type='time'], [type='url'], [type='week'] {
  color: red;
}
```

I highly recommend [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/) for experimenting with SASS code. Can choose version to some extent, and use either SASS or SCSS.