# Is there a way to write custom selectors in LESS?

Tags: css, less

I'll give an example of what I'd like to do.

```
:all() {
    &, 
    &:link,
    &:visited,
    &:active,
    &:focus
}
```

The above is an imagining of a 'custom selector' that itself returns a selection of all pseudo-classes of an anchor tag, minus :hover.

I'd like to use it as a selector like so:

```
.menu {
    a.top-level:all, span {
        color: @dormant-grey;
    }
    a.top-level:hover {
        color: @off-black;
    }
}
```

And for it to generate:

```
.menu a.top-level,
.menu a.top-level:link,
.menu a.top-level:visited,
.menu a.top-level:active,
.menu a.top-level:focus,
.menu span {
    color: #686868;
}
.menu a.top-level:hover {
    color: #22282a;
}
```

So I hope I'm communicating clearly what the question is. Is there a way to reuse **selections**?

Note that this is different than passing styles into a mixin. Passing styles into a mixin, to achieve the same thing, would require repeating the styling. Once to pass into the mixin, and then again for all the other selections that the mixin does not handle. Its also what I'm doing now and I'm finding that it isn't worth using the mixin because I've had to repeat myself so many times that I'm just going to pull it out.

So I hope that is clear. I'm asking if there is a way to reuse a **selection**, not a style. If less can't do it, is there a language that can?

Comment: Sass and LESS are not interchangeable.  Sass *can* do this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369600/styling-a-specific-set-of-input-types-in-a-reusable-way-with-sass

Comment: SASS can do this, while LESS can't!

Comment: Just to double confirm, is [this method](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/bHpLd) the same as what you say you have already tried?

Comment: @Harry Yep thats the one. The part where you have to repeat yourself is when you want to apply styling to more than just .all()

Comment: On second thoughts, why not use `extend` on one selector which is a part of the `.all` like [here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/bHpLd) (for the items which the mixin does not handle)?

Comment: @Harry Darn.. I figured as much but I wanted to confirm. I like SASS but I'm in a position where we're already commited to LESS.
My question was answered Ultimately by Praveen, but illuminated in part by cimmanon and yourself.
While Nico's answer was useful, doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AndrewHoffman: Did you check my previous comment about the `extend`. It is not great or the most efficient, but I think it is a decent enough add-on to the current one. One problem with this approach is that the `extend` doesn't take `&` as a selector, so we have to manually type the full selector.

Comment: @AndrewHoffman you are right, my answer was not really on topic, since you explicit wanted a less solution. I removed the post.

Comment: @NicoO no problemo, it was helpful to see what the future may hold for web development. :D

Comment: @Harry That might work if I could :extend a mixin.

Comment: Honestly I can't understand why it's so hot here: [gist](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/fe050a871e13c8a80f60#file-25668879-1-less) and for optimization of duplicated styles use `--clean-css --clean-option=--advanced` (and yes, obviously `extend`ing mixins or even more better [#1694](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1694) would do it more clean).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(So to not leave this one w/o an answer - copying my comment above):

```
.all(@-) {
    &,
    &:link,
    &:visited,
    &:active,
    &:focus {
        @-();
    }
}

.menu {
    .span {
        color: red;
    }
    a.top-level {
        .all({.span});
        :hover {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously produces duplicated styles for `.span` and `a.top-level` family but as soon as you care and generate a minified CSS version `--clean-css --clean-option=--advanced` option will eliminate duplicated styles with love.